# Random angle bounce

Tags: c#

Im learning how to use c# for videogames and im starting with something basic, a ball that bounces with walls. Now I want that the ball can bounce randomly in any angle and at the same time maintaining the speed. Does someone know how could i do it?

```
using System;

namespace PELOTAREBOTING_VERSION_PADRES
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        bool loop = true;
        bool sumarX = true;
        bool sumarY = true;
        double velocidad = 1.0;
        double angulo;
        int intrandom;

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Empieza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double X = Pelota.Location.X;
            double Y = Pelota.Location.Y;
            Random random = new Random();
            Random angulorandom = new Random();
            angulorandom.Next(2);

            intrandom = (int)Math.Round(angulo);
            angulo = random.NextDouble() * 2 * Math.PI; // Ángulo aleatorio en radianes

            do
            {
                Pelota.Location = new Point((int)X + 1, (int)Y + 1);

                if (X >= 300 || X <= 170)
                {
                    int direction = random.Next(3); // Genera un número aleatorio entre 0 y 2

                    if (direction == 0)
                    { sumarX = random.Next(2) == 0;} // Probabilidad de cambiar la dirección horizontal
                    else if (direction == 1)
                        sumarY = !sumarY; // Cambia la dirección vertical
                    else
                        sumarX = !sumarX; // Cambia la dirección horizontal
                }

                cionvert
                if (X >= 300)
                {
                    sumarX = false;
                    Random numeroazar = new Random(0);
                    velocidad = random.Next(0);
                }
                if (X <= 170)
                { sumarX = true; }

                if (sumarX == true)
                { X = X + 1; }
                if (sumarX == false)
                { X = X - 1; }

                if (Y >= 300)
                { sumarY = false; }
                if (Y == 170)
                { sumarY = true; }

                if (sumarY == true)
                { Y = Y + 1; }
                if (sumarY == false)
                { Y = Y - 1; }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                if (Pelota.Location.X == 0) // if ball goes out of bounds to coordinate X = 0
                { loop = false; }
            } while (loop);
        }
    }
}
```

I cant think of any solution, thats why i need help.

Comment: (1) Detect the collision, (2) find the wall's normal vector, (3) throw a RNG from -90 to +90 degrees (+/- pi/2), (3) rotate the normal vector according to the randomized angle, (4). set the ball's velocity to the resulting vector, settings its length the same as the ball's original velocity vector length. (5) profit

Comment: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Algebra/Algebra_and_Trigonometry_1e_(OpenStax)/10%3A_Further_Applications_of_Trigonometry/10.03%3A_Polar_Coordinates